# (Potential Visual Studio Bug) Visual Studio 2019 Error List showing errors that should not exist as that error isn't actually present

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, build-error

This is for an ASP.NET Webforms project.

On the .ASPX file there is a :

```
<span id="FooterTextSpan" runat="server">[Redacted]</span>
```

I am editing the span from the code-behind (ASPX.cs file), and in Visual Studio, I see this:

[image: The name 'FooterTextSpan' does not exist in the current context]

And yet, it is there in the `.ASPX` file.

In the `@Page...` declaration the correct `CodeBehind` is specified, and it `Inherits` from the correct location, too.

The project does not build if you try to build and don't do the 'hacky-fix' below:

To fix this, you can go into the `.ASPX` page, and add a space, then delete the space, and the error just vanishes.

How do I resolve this so I do not need to do this 'hacky-fix', as it is happening in other files, too.

Comment: I don’t know the answer to this, but my guess is that your `aspx.designer.cs` file isn’t either not getting generated—or is not getting _re_generated—when you update your control tree. IntelliSense relies on the `aspx.designer.cs` file to act as the glue between your `aspx` and `aspx.cs` files. I’d start by looking at that file, and monitoring its state vs. these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanguine,

I have met this **IntelliSense misreport problem** for few times and it is really annoying. Fortunately, it is rare.

If you have tried

1. clean and rebuild the solution or
2. delete the .vs folder to clean the cache 
   and the problem is still there, here is a workaround.

As you can see in VS, there are few of options for selection in the "Error list" section.

[image]

You can select "Build Only" so that the error list only shows the error from build.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for this response. 1 & 2 didn't work but the last did which is a shame as the first 2 would have been more ideal.